# Separating data retrieved through mysql, node and rendered in handlebars

Tags: mysql, node.js, handlebars.js

I have a nav bar, which retrieves the link titles from mysql using node and handlebars, I want them to go to different links, what is the way to separate the data so that each link is clickable.

I have attached my handlebars logic and the nav bar.

Thanks in advance.
Mohamed

[NAVBAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpGy4.png)

[HBS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3mTC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mind to use the `<a></a>` TAG?

```
{{#each links}}
<a href="{{this.links}}">{{this.links}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I have now found and implemented my solution I did use the a tag also

Answer (score 0):

[hbs for links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZlsp.png)

So I used an a tag, my links are controlled by jQuery and load page blocks based on which link is clicked, I used the hbs {{code}}, which was also the same as my id's used in my jQuery, which load blocks with class names which are also the same as shown in image 2.

[hbs for page sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3tTy.png)

Handlebars is a great view engine! Bit of perseverance and I got my solution to work exactly how I wanted to!

Thanks Cyrille for your solution

Comment: Well you can accept my answer if that makes the way to fix the problem

Comment: I will accept your solution however the note here is any relevant tag can be used if it has an id and if jQuery is being used, for a no jQuery navigation the a tag will suffice. I appreciate your help, thanks